# Can I change the search order in the Chrome Omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

Is it possible to change search order that the Omnibar uses?

We have a few internal webpages, for example, one called http://openoptions.

When the users type "openoptions" in the Omnibar, the omnibar searches for it on google.co.uk, and suggests "Did you mean go to http://openoptions/?" but we'd rather it went straight to the webpage first rather than going to the search.

All of our installations go via search engine first, but weirdly, one, single machine does work in the way we'd like, but we don't know how it's been set to do it.

I hope that made sense. I do have a couple of images to describe the issue

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: Suggestion: Examine the extensions installed on that single machine.

Comment: All installations only have two extensions enabled, one for Foxit PDF and the other for OpenText Desktop Browser. I've disabled them, etc. but it didn't make any difference. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: It seems to me that you need to compare other settings or installed products. This is too vast for me to make any more suggestions.